# UIActionSheet fifth button doesn't work

Tags: ios, uiactionsheet

I have a UIActionSheet in a universal app that contains 5 buttons.  The problem is, you can't press the last (fifth button).  I tried removing the destructive button (which made six), but the fifth button still doesn't work.  It works fine on the iPad, but there's clearly more real-estate and it's presented in a popover...

What's going on here???

Comment: It's tough to say without seeing your code that generates your `UIActionSheet`

Comment: Actually not, I just figured it out.  You have to present it from a toolbar or tabbar.  If you present fromView it doesn't work on iphone.  I changed to showFromToolBar and it works fine.  Unfortunately, I finally realized this right after posting... of course...

Answer (score 0):

Of course, as soon as I post this question, I find the solution.

For anyone else looking at this: 
On iPhone you must present from tabBar or toolBar to get full real-estate so 6 total buttons can be handled.  You cannot present fromView...

Comment: The documentations say that you can present from a view.  What leads you to conclude otherwise?